# How to get data from Cloud Firestore by current date?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have data list on firebase, and I want to display my data based on today, I have been try like this, but it does not work

```
_getFirebaseData() async {
    CollectionReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection('product').where('date').startAt('2019-06-11').getDocuments();

    ref.documents.forEach((document) {
      print(document['name']);
    });
}
```

date format in my firebase is string like this : '2019-06-11 15:21:28',
thanks for your help

Comment: Could you specify what exactly is not working, i.e. if you get an error or something similar? Also, why are you not using timestamps or are you using them? In the Firebase Console, you can manually add data and use a `timestamp`. The same can be done in Flutter and any other client library.

Comment: Can you also show a picture of a document that you're trying to get with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
Firestore.instance.collection('product').where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '2019-06-11').
```

This is based on reading the [usage](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#usage) section of the FlutterFire documentation.

This assumes that you're storing the data as a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. If you're storing it as a different format or type, you will need to pass in that format/type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the orderBy method. It will look like this:

```
db.collection('my-collection').orderBy('date').get().then((snapshot)=> {     
   snapshot.doc.forEach((doc) => {
       return SomeWidget();
})
```